# How to pass a td text to echo it somewhere else (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, text, echo, pass-through

I got a loop which puts multiple tables on the screen with the same class, same markup but other content, which depends on the outcome of the query.

So for example the output will be

```
<table class='tablestyleorchideevraag'>
<tr><td>hi</td></tr>
</table>

<table class='tablestyleorchideevraag'>
<tr><td>bye</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can i pass the td text .onclick() and how can I GET the text to echo it later on the screen after clicking?

So, when i click table with class='tablestyleorchideevraag' it needs to store the td text somewhere. When I click the table with td text hi, it needs to save the text hi. When I click the table with td text bye, it needs to save the text bye.

When clicked I want to echo the stored text

Comment: What does your jQuery attempt look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastClickedValue = "";

    $('.tablestyleorchideevraag').on('click', function(){
       var value = $(this).find('tr:first td:first').html();
       lastClickedValue = value;
       console.log( value );
    });

    $('someotherselector').on('click', function(){
        console.log( 'The last value you clicked was: '+ lastClickedValue );
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to store the data now in something variable like $myvalue = "td value"

Comment: Sure, you can store it in another variable with a scope outside the closure that can be referenced later.

Comment: How?

Like;

$('.tablestyleorchideevraag').on('click', function(){
   var value = $(this).find('tr:first td:first').html();
   //store it here in $myvalue, please
   console.log( value );
});

Comment: I have made a td with class="test", so $('.test').on('click', function(){
        console.log( 'The last value you clicked was: '+ lastClickedValue );
    });

but it doesn't echo or make appear anything